# Identification of a system of equation with a parameter in the exponent

Tags: nonlinear-regression, identifiability

I'm trying to proof identification for the following system of $N$ equations:

$$ y\times(1-\sigma) = x^{(1-\sigma)} - 1 + \alpha \times ( z^{(1-\sigma)} - 1) + \beta \times ( w^{(1-\sigma)} - 1) $$

the roman letters are data (strictly positive and finite numbers), while the greek letters are the parameters to be identified. That is I'm looking for $\hat{\sigma}, \hat{\alpha}, \text{ and } \hat{\beta}$.

I know that if $\sigma = 0$ then the full rank condition is a sufficient condition. What about the case where $\sigma \neq 0$?

Restriction: $\sigma \neq 1$

Comment: This looks like an unstable way to apply a Box-Cox transformation to all regressors in multiple regression. It's unstable because $\sigma=1$ will *always* work. It's a mistake to multiply both sides by $1-\sigma$, anyway, *because it implicitly multiplies the unwritten error term,* too. Instead such a model ought to be written $$y-f_p(x)=\alpha f_p(z)+\beta f_p(w)+\epsilon$$ where $p=1-\sigma$, $f_p(t)=(t^p-1)/p$ for $p\ne 0$, $f_0(t)=\lim_{p\to 0}f_p(t)=\log(t)$, and $\epsilon$ is random. Unless $z$ and $w$ are linearly dependent, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ will be identified for almost all $p$.

Comment: A restriction (didn't mention, sorry) is that $\sigma \neq 1$. There is no error term in this system of equations. I'm trying to establish identification here, not estimating the parameters (which can be done by the method of moments). Therefore, the argument I'm trying to put forward is that if I have 2 such equations and the full-rank condition holds then $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are identified if $\sigma \neq 1$. That is, I can solve for $\alpha$ and $\beta$. I'm not sure how to identify $\sigma$.

Comment: I'm trying to show identification of $\sigma$ by showing that there cannot be 2 set of parameters (i.e. $\{\alpha, \beta, \sigma\}$ and $\{\alpha', \beta', \sigma'\}$) that, when plugged in, give the same dependent variable (vector $y$). Thank you so much!

Comment: The only way in which you could validly claim there "is no error term" would be for there to be at least one tuple $(\alpha,\beta,\sigma)$ for which those equations hold *exactly*.  In that case you have a purely mathematical problem: it has no statistical nature.

Comment: yes, this is the identification part. In order to estimate the model, I need to show that the model is identified, which means that if I have enough equations, I can just solve it.

Comment: According to your previous comment, this is not a statistical model--so there is nothing to estimate.  If you have more equations than unknowns (that is, more than three equations) then you *must* include an error term.  Otherwise it's unlikely there will be any solutions at all.

Comment: in a linear set-up, like a regression, the identification step is counting the equations and making sure that the equations are more than the unknowns. This is enough if the vectors are not linearly dependent. Without this identification step, you can't proceed to the estimation. In a non-linear set-up, in general, counting equations is no-more enough to establish identification of the parameters. In order to estimate the model (adding the error term), you need to make sure the parameters are identified first.